# Are there mtDNA societies like there are surname societies for Y-DNA?

Tags: dna, mitochondrial-dna

Males get their Y-DNA from their father and both males and females get their mtDNA from their mother. Because surnames generally follow the Y-DNA, groups of individuals with the same Y-DNA can find each other thru surname societies. Is there an equivalent to a surname society for people who share mtDNA? Ie are there any societies arranged around matrilineal lines instead of surnames?

Comment: Possibly such a society was established in the nineteenth century but their husbands made the organisers close it down. On a serious note, the preponderance of name societies does reflect the (once) prevailing view on good genealogy. Perhaps the availability of data on mitochiondrial inheritance will cause a shift.

Answer (score 4):

At the [familytreedna site](http://www.familytreedna.com/public/mtDNA_K/) there is a description of Project Katrine.

> Project created January 9, 2006. "Katrine," the founding mother of mitochondrial DNA haplogroup K, was one of the "Seven Daughters of Eve" as listed in the 2001 book of that title by Bryan Sykes.

If there was one *society* for each haplogroup, it might be too large to be useful for finding cousins.

Also few people would be able to trace their matrilineal line back far enough . Pople who took [Randy's Saturday Night Fun challenge](http://www.geneamusings.com/2012/09/saturday-night-genealogy-fun-what-is.html) seemed to hit a brickwall fairly quickly.